# Mount NTFS on Ubuntu start up - rc.local vs fstab

Tags: ntfs, mount

I've found out two ways to automount a NTFS partition on Ubuntu start up.

1. File `/etc/rc.local`:

   ```
   mount -t ntfs /dev/sda8 /mnt/data/
   ```
2. Or by `fstab`:

   ```
   UUID=1C02CB8502CB627E /media/data/ ntfs defaults 0 0
   ```

   - Is there any difference between them?
   - Is one more recommended than other? Which should I choose?

Comment: One quick note, in Ubuntu add uid=xxxx to the fstab entry. (If you are the only user that would be uid=1000) Reason being that Ubuntu then creates a Trash folder and nautilus then has "Move to Trash" option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the fstab; that is the standard place for automatically mounting volumes.

rc scripts are intended to be used for running generic startup commands and launching startup services.

As a side note, you don't have to use the UUID in the fstab if you really don't want to, it should work equally as well using /dev/sda8

Comment: Thanks! :) Another question: the permissions and owner of the folder are autoset to `drwxrwxrwx 1 root root`. I've tried `chown` and `chmod` commands but I could not change it to `drwxr-xr-x 1 victorhugo victorhugo`. Do you know why it is happening?

Comment: Have a look at some of the mounting options available to you
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab
You can replace "defaults" with more customised options. But be wary, you are using an NTFS file system which doesn't use the standard unix permissions, so attempting to change them may not even make sense. Just make sure you have read and write access the file.

Comment: /dev/sda8 could change, the UUID is, at its name says, unique

Comment: Tutorial: http://www.howtoadvice.com/2014/03/08/how-to-permanently-mount-an-ntfs-external-hard-drive-to-a-linux-server/

Answer (score 2):

Unable to login/ssh to server,**if the hdd(sda8) gets died or corrupted somehow** and its entry is present in fstab. but if its entry is in rc.local then i'm able get the login.